# Check if a column is auto incremented in Sybase with JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, metadata, sybase

To check if a column is auto incremented i can do the following

```
Connection con = ...    
DatabaseMetaData meta = con.getMetaData();
ResultSet metaCols = meta.getColumns(catalog, schema, table, "%");
while ( metaCols.next() )   
     String value = rs.getString("IS_AUTOINCREMENT")    
  ...
```

works fine except with Sybase databases. I've tried it with the jTDS and JConnect drivers, but with both drivers I get the this exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name IS_AUTOINCREMENT.
```

Is there another the get find out, whether a column in Sybase is auto incremented or not?
I thought "IS_AUTOINCREMENT" is a feature with JDBC4 and jTDS is a JDBC4 compatible driver.

Comment: for future comers, you can check my below answer for a query to check if column is identity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sp_help  delivers all the information I need.
This SP returns several ResultSets.
The third ResultSet contains the information I need.

```
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
stmt.executeQuery("sp_help " + table);
stmt.getMoreResults();
stmt.getMoreResults();
ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();
//...
while( rs.next() )
   boolean identity = rs.getBoolean("Identity");
```

Answer (score 3):

Sybase uses 'identity' columns rather than 'default autoincrement' which is why I believe you are getting this message.

Try checking if TYPE_NAME column contains keyword "identity".

The behaviour of identity columns is a little different also, but that is an aside.

Comment: the columns identity or IDENTITY does not exist. But thanks for the advice. See my answer I found after your hint.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I misunderstood as you have found below using sp_help if the identity column contains a 1 then the column is an identity.

There are also other methods available. I was concentrating on Java methods when I could have given you the answer in seconds had I known you would be happy with SQL commands such as sp_help, sp_columns and selecting from systemtables.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

What version of JConnect are you using? Try using 6. It should work using:

DatabaseMetaData.getTypeInfo()

PS. Sorry new to the site, not enough points to comment on your post :(

Comment: DatabaseMetaData.getTypeInfo() returns only the data type supported by the database. But this information is not helpful to find an identity column.

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest way to get the identity information

```
ResultSet tableInfo = tableInfoQuery.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " WHERE 1=2");
ResultSetMetaData rsMetaData = tableInfo.getMetaData();
for (int i = 1; i < = rsMetaData.getColumnCount(); i++)
{rsMetaData.isAutoIncrement(i);}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a query to check the column is identity, you can use system table `syscolumns`. So as per [sybase infocenter](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36274.1570/html/tables/X14340.htm) the value 128 of column `status` in syscolumns is identity.

```
select * from sysobjects so
inner join syscolumns sc on so.id=sc.id
where so.name='EX_EMPLOYEE' and sc.name='ID' and sc.status=128
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Connection conn; <...create connection...>
ResultSet rs1 = conn.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT * FROM table1");
ResultSetMetaData rsmd1 = rs1.getMetadata();
for (int i=1;i<rsmd1.getColumnCount();i++) { 
switch (rsmd1.getColumnTypeName(i).toUpperCase())
  case "ID":
    System.out.println("Identity column: " + rsmd1.getColumnName(i));
    break;
  default: 
}
}
```